# Rellenar array bidimensional recursivo

Tags: java

quiero saber como puedo rellenar una matriz bidimensional de caracteres NxN recursivamente, con caracteres aleatorios. Hasta ahora tengo hecho esto, pero solo me rellena una linea.

```
public static void rellenarRecursivo(char[][] soup, int i, int j) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    String abecedary = "abcdefghijklmñopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int words = abecedary.length() - 1;
    //Caso base. Mientras que el contador sea menor que la longitud de la matriz se sigue la recursividad.
    if (i < soup.length - 1) {
        //Solo se rellenarán las posiciones que estén vacias.
        if (soup[i][j] == '·') {
            soup[i][j] = abecedary.charAt(rnd.nextInt(words));
            rellenarRecursivo(soup, i + 1, j+1);

        }

    }

}
```

Gracias

Comment: Date cuenta que solo esta iterando sobre `i`. Necesitas iterar tambien sobre `j`

Comment: ¿Es esto un ejercicio de clase? Usar recursividad para recorrer una matriz no es especialmente eficiente

Comment: Si esto es un ejercicio de clase. por favor si me podeis poner el codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que tenemos las dimensiones iniciales de la matriz...
Declaras una única instancia de las variables que van a hacer falta

```
private static Random rnd = new Random();
private static final String abecedary = "abcdefghijklmñopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
private static int words = abecedary.length() - 1;
```

Cuando se ejecuta el main, inicializamos el array e iteramos sobre las filas (incide i) llamando al metodo recursivo que se encargará de rellenar las columnas de cada fila.

```
char[][] soup = new char[5][5];

for (int i = 0; i < soup.length; i++) {
    rellenarFila(soup, i, 0);
}
```

El metodo recursivo se utiliza para rellenar las columnas de la matriz (indice j) mientras queden columnas vacías.

```
public static void rellenarFila(char[][] soup, int i, int j) {
    soup[i][j] = abecedary.charAt(rnd.nextInt(words));
    if (j < soup[i].length - 1) {
        rellenarFila(soup, i, j + 1);
    }
}
```

Luego imprimimos la salida

```
for (int i = 0; i < soup.length; i++) {
        StringBuilder fila = new StringBuilder();
        fila.append("Fila " + i + ": ");
        for (int j = 0; j < soup.length; j++) {
            fila.append(soup[i][j]);
            fila.append(",");
        }
        System.out.println(fila);
    }
```

Dando como resultado:

```
Fila 0: C,y,y,s,X,
Fila 1: s,V,D,V,Y,
Fila 2: c,Q,X,m,ñ,
Fila 3: L,U,X,K,v,
Fila 4: M,A,g,x,m,
```

La clase entera queda así

```
 import java.util.Random;

    public class Pruebas {

        //Solo es necesaria una instancia de estos objetos.
    private static Random rnd = new Random();
    private static final String abecedary = "abcdefghijklmñopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    private static int words = abecedary.length() - 1;

    /**
     * Main method.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char[][] soup = new char[5][5];

        for (int i = 0; i < soup.length; i++) {
            rellenarFila(soup, i, 0);
        }

        //Salida
        for (int i = 0; i < soup.length; i++) {
            StringBuilder fila = new StringBuilder();
            fila.append("Fila " + i + ": ");
            for (int j = 0; j < soup.length; j++) {
                fila.append(soup[i][j]);
                fila.append(",");
            }
            System.out.println(fila);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Metodo recursivo que rellena las columnas de cada fila.
     * @param soup
     * @param i
     * @param j
     */
    public static void rellenarFila(char[][] soup, int i, int j) {
        soup[i][j] = abecedary.charAt(rnd.nextInt(words));
        if (j < soup[i].length - 1) {
            rellenarFila(soup, i, j + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La recursividad es de gran ayuda a la hora de generar valores con un comportamiento de serie, es decir, un comportamiento que permite ver la variación y la generación de una regla.

Los arreglos se recorren de forma ascendente o descendente y aunque de forma normal su recorrido se da en ciclo foreach o ciclo for tradicional, también es posible usar una función recursiva. Hay que recordar que una función recursiva se asemeja a la variante de un ciclo, es decir, toma valores en forma de pila y si el recorrido se debe hacer de forma ascendente, entonces el llamado a la función seria:  rec p + 1 o si el recorrido se hace en forma descendente, entonces el llamado seria: rec n-1.

Comparto un programa en Java que permite generar el recorrido recursivo descendente de una matriz >> https://tutorias.co/recursividad-java-recorrido-recursivo-descendente-de-una-matriz

Comment: Deberías agregar aquí el código del enlace y solo dejarlo como referencia, pues con el tiempo se corre el riesgo de que dicho link quede innacesible